# How do I apply a max-width to an input field form-control with a trailing secondary button in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I attempt to apply a maximum width to an input field, it positions the secondary button as if the input field didn't have a maximum width.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22026/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" maxlength="10" class="form-control datefield" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button id="btnClearDate" class="btn btn-secondary btn-default" type="button">Clear</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.datefield {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

How can I get the secondary button to correctly sit next to the text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using display:inline-block;

https://jsfiddle.net/ex3ntia/DTcHh/22030/

```
.input-group-btn {display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is laid out by using a grid system. You will need to adjust your design layout to accomplish what you are looking to achieve.

What is happening now is all you are doing is shrinking down the size of the input box, but not the actual grid cell.

try adjusting just the cell or placing the form-group elements within a cell then within a targeting element you can shrink.

Try this,

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.shrink {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="shrink">
        <label class="control-label">Date</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" maxlength="10" class="form-control datefield" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button id="btnClearDate" class="btn btn-secondary btn-default" type="button">Clear</button>
            </span>
          </div><!-- .input-group -->
        </div><!-- .shrink -->
    </div><!-- .form-group -->
  </div><!-- .row -->
</div> <!-- .container -->
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The span was not being displayed inline. I assume this was changed with the input-group-btn class. Here is the new code (I named the new class ):

```js
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.datefield {
  max-width: 100px;
}

.buttoncleardiv {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" maxlength="10" class="form-control datefield" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
      <span class="input-group-btn buttoncleardiv">
          <button id="btnClearDate" class="btn btn-secondary btn-default" type="button">Clear</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The JS Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/absn703m/4/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution leaves a noticeable space between the elements and puts the button 1 pixel lower, causing it to be misaligned with the input box.